# Error "Sorry, I need a wp-config-sample.php file to work from. Please re-upload this file from your WordPress installation."

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I have been getting this error while installing Wordpress locally:

"Error establishing a database connection This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can't contact the database server at localhost. This could mean your host's database server is down."

I searched the web for a solution. Most people said to check if MySql server is online (MAMP says it is) or change the wp-config-sample.php file.

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'wp_demo');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

I have done it and still to no avail. The last step was changing the "wp-config-sample.php" filename to "wp-config.php" which netted me this error:

"Sorry, I need a wp-config-sample.php file to work from. Please re-upload this file from your WordPress installation."

I am using Win 7, MAMP 3.3.1  PHP 7.1.5. Localhost is on port 8888. MySql is port 8889

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change db_host from localhost to 127.0.0.1:8889

Comment: I have changed to both possibilities and it doesn't work. BTW, should the db_host be inputted into the wordpress "Database Host" field? (i have tried that)

Comment: @BarAkiva what happens when you visit http://localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin/

Comment: 1. Yes I did define it as you say. 2. phpMyAdmin screen comes up. I have already created a DB named wp_demo

Comment: Holy crap it worked now that I tried it for the 100th time

Comment: This is marked as an answer but really don't answer the question. Just tells what to do but not why. This should be a comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error you are facing because of incorrect database configuration for instance DB_USER & DB_PASSWORD. There is no need to change/rename/copy/pase the file name i.e- wp-config-sample.php

You need to carefully configure the DB_NAME & DB_PASSWORD otherwise you will face such errors during db connectivity. I was facing the same issue but when i set authentication phpMyAdmin to no passowrd the installation goes continue. In this case you need to set no password in phpMyAdmin. Than start configuation properly:

Open the configuration file with notepad and carefully change the database details, than save with existing name. Furthermore when you connect to database, the config file will automatically create in the web directory. Now change according to your need and requirements.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wp_demo');

/** MySQL database default username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database default password you can leave it blank.
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Answer (score -1):

It's an easy fix, change your wordpress folder permission and XAMPP too if need be

Comment: A useful answer would say what permissions were required, and provide the command(s) that would change the permissions.